# Flexform displayCond for items?

Tags: typo3, flexform

Is it possible to change the items from one setting with displayCond or something different?

Example:

```
                   <settings.setting1>
                        <TCEforms>
                            <label>Label</label>
                            <onChange>reload</onChange>
                            <config>
                                <type>select</type>
                                <renderType>selectSingle</renderType>
                                <items type="array">
                                    <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0">Item 1</numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1">item 1</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                    <numIndex index="1" type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0">Item 2</numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="Item 2">children</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                </items>
                                <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                                <size>1</size>
                            </config>
                        </TCEforms>
                    </settings.setting1>

                    <settings.setting2>
                        <TCEforms>
                            <label>Label</label>
                            <config>
                                <type>select</type>
                                <renderType>selectSingle</renderType>
                                <items type="array">
                                    <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0">Only if setting1 is Item 1</numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1">item1</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                    <numIndex index="1" type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0">Only if setting1 is item2</numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1">item2</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                </items>
                                <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                            </config>
                        </TCEforms>
                    </settings.setting1>
```

Is it possible that `setting2` just shows `item1` if `setting1` is `item1` ? Or should I use two different settings for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is [possible as documented](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/11.5/en-us/Columns/Properties/DisplayCond.html#access-values-in-a-flexform):

```xml
<displayCond>FIELD:settings.setting1:=:item1</displayCond>
```

Comment: But then settings2 would not be displayed, if setting1 has item1 selected. But settings2 should be displayed the whole time, just the items in settings2 should not be displayed

Comment: In this case you need an [`itemsProcFunc`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/11.5/en-us/ColumnsConfig/CommonProperties/ItemsProcFunc.html#tca-property-itemsprocfunc).